# How Can I migrate website from One server to Another

Tags: server, cpanel, web-hosting

I want to migrate my multiple sites from one server to another. The source server where all the files are now residing is non WHM/Cpanel based. The target server is WHM/Cpanel based. Previously i used to do transfers using cpanel to cpanel transfers from WHM dashboard but now I am don't know what is the proper way to migrate the files.

Can someone please let me know of any effective way to properly migrate all the files.

Answer (score 0):

If the source server has some panel like DirectAdmin then you may find a script to do so else wise you would need to proceed manual way i.e

1. create cPanel accounts of all the websites or add as addon domain in a same cPanel account (whatever setup you wish to do).
2. rsync files into respective home dir of the domain mapped with
3. dump all the database on the source server and copy on your whm server, further importing in whm database name style. Import one by one.
4. Make sure you make changes to website config file as per new database name.